# motor oscillates after diff_drive_controller configuration

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-canopen, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have configured the canopen_motor_node of my robot to use a DiffDriveController, but once I start publishing angular velocities in the /cmd_vel topic the movement is not smooth, i.e. the robot turns then stops, then continues the angular movement, then stops and so on. After a while it gets stable.

I thought it could be a problem related to the pid controller embedded inside the motors (Dunkermotoren BG75CI) because the movement seems to be like an underdamped second order response trying to reach the desired velocity value but when I used socketcan_bridge_node to send velocity values it works properly. So now i think it could be related to the differential drive controller or to the frequency of publishing. I put here my controller configuration

```
# The joint state controller handles publishing transforms for any moving joints
joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50

# Differential Controllers ---------------------------------------

diff_drive_controller:
    type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
    left_wheel: 'left_wheel_joint'
    right_wheel: 'right_wheel_joint'
    publish_rate: 1000.0
    pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
    wheel_separation: 0.60125
    wheel_radius: 0.1

    required_drive_mode: 2

    # Wheel separation and radius multipliers
    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
    wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0

    # Velocity commands timeout [s]
    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25

    # Base frame_id
    base_frame_id: base_link

    # Velocity and acceleration limits
    linear:
      x:
        has_velocity_limits    : true
        max_velocity           : 4.0  # m/s
        min_velocity           : -4.0 # m/s
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration       : 1  # m/s^2
        min_acceleration       : -1 # m/s^2
        has_jerk_limits        : true
        max_jerk               : 5.0  # m/s^3
    angular:
      z:
        has_velocity_limits    : true
        max_velocity           : 3  # rad/s
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration       : 1  # rad/s^2
        has_jerk_limits        : true
        max_jerk               : 1  # rad/s^3
```

Also my canopen configuration

```
bus:
  device: can0
  loopback: false
  driver_plugin: can::SocketCANInterface
  master_allocator: canopen::SimpleMaster::Allocator

sync:
  interval_ms: 0 # set to 0 to disable sync
  update_ms: 10 #update interval of control loop, must be set explecitly if sync is disabled
  overflow: 0 # overflow sync counter at value or do not set it (0, default)
# heartbeat: # simple heartbeat producer, optional!
  # rate: 20 # heartbeat rate
  # msg: "77f#05" # message to send, cansend format: heartbeat of node 127 with status 5=Started

# struct syntax
nodes:
  node1:
    id: 1
    eds_pkg: bluerobot_basic # optionals package  name for relative path
    name: right_wheel_joint
    eds_file: "/eds/Dunker_BG75mi.eds" # path to EDS/DCF file

  node2:
    id: 2
    eds_pkg: bluerobot_basic
    name: left_wheel_joint # optional name
    eds_file: "/eds/Dunker_BG75mi.eds" # absolute name
    dcf_overlay:
        "4911sub1" : "0x1B"   #Reverse flag

use_realtime_period: true

defaults:
  motor_allocator: canopen::Motor402::Allocator # select allocator for motor layer
  motor_layer: # settings passed to motor layer (plugin-specific)
    switching_state: 5 # (Operation_Enable), state for mode switching
  pos_from_device: "(obj6063*2*pi)/(4096*23)" # actual position [m] -> rad
  vel_to_device: "rint(23*(vel*60/(2*pi)))" # rad/s -> rev/min
  vel_from_device: "(obj606C*2*pi)/(60*23)" # actual velocity [rev/min] -> rad/s
#  pos_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(pos)*1000)" # rad -> m
#  eff_to_device: "rint(eff)" # just round to integer
#  eff_from_device: "0" # unset
```

Edit1:

I also let you the EDS dictionary of my motors.

[Dictionary object](https://github.com/afvillamil231/robot_project/blob/master/Dunker_BG75mi.eds)

Edit 2:

I plot the target velocity value, the actual velocity and the velocity feedback in each motor and I got the behavior in the next [video](https://youtu.be/g1NVAast_Aw). It seems like actually the target velocity value is oscillating so the problem has nothing to do with the variables inside the motor but with the commands sent by the ROS controller.

**There is something like PID parameters in the configuration of canopen_motor_node?**

Edit 3: Here is the URDF of my blue robot.

[URDF Description](https://github.com/afvillamil231/robot_project/tree/master/urdf)
The blue_robot.urdf is the main file.

Edit 4: [/odom topic plot](https://github.com/afvillamil231/robot_project/blob/master/image.png) for angular velocity in the z axis.

Thank you for your help, if you need more information please let me know!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327603/motor-oscillates-after-diff_drive_controller-configuration/) by [af.villamil231](https://answers.ros.org/users/40998/af.villamil231/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-07-09**:
Do you specify any joint velocity limits in your URDF (or a separate yaml)?

**Comment by [af.villamil231](https://answers.ros.org/users/40998/af.villamil231/) on 2019-07-10**:
Yes! Thank you Mathias. I updated the post with the URDF directory. The joints are in the blue_wheel.urdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no PID controller in between, `canopen_motor_node` just forwards the target commands.

BUT: the joint limits interface might adapt the command according to the limits, which [does not work well](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/141) in some cases.
You could either remove the limits from URDF or set `enforce_limits: False` in your controller config (next to `required_drive_mode`)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [af.villamil231](https://answers.ros.org/users/40998/af.villamil231/) on 2019-07-22**:
I already solved my problem, you were right Thank you! Actually I have deleted the limits from the URDF but not from the ParameterServer (From the controller in Yaml). Once I removed them from both files the robot started working properly. Thank you again!